# How to check wxPython release from python GUI (IDLE)?

Tags: python, wxpython

I am a newbie in wxPython.
I have opened up a python GUI (IDLE) where I am writing my code.
import wx works fine for me hence there is no doubt that wx is working fine

Now, I would like to print the wxPython release. How do I do it from IDLE editor?

(It may seem silly, I couldn't get the exact command)
I would like to get my output like: Your WxPython release is: 2.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see here how:

http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/Determine-version-of-wxPython-at-runtime-td2292695.html

EDIT:

```
wx.__version__
```

Comment: Fantastic, with a small modification, print print wx.__version__ works! I would accept this answer even though the other one too works.

Comment: You should NOT import the wxPython module. It has been deprecated for years and I believe it has been removed in Phoenix

Answer (score 1):

You can do either of the following:

```
import wx

wx.version()
wx.__version__
```